# How to insert dropdownbutton value to databse mysql using flutter

Tags: mysql, database, flutter, dart

I'm new on flutter framework, i have some problem with dropdownbutton. How to save selected dropdownbutton to the mysql database

This code is actually works to save to the mysqldb for textfield. But how to get selected dropdownbutton value

```
    class FormOrtuView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormOrtuViewState createState() => _FormOrtuViewState();
}

class _FormOrtuViewState extends State<FormOrtuView> {
  String _dropdownValueAgm = 'Katolik';

  final _key = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Insert to database code:

```
sumbit(String namaAyah,agamaAyah) async {
    var ayah = {
      "id_register": idReg,
      "nama_ayah": namaAyah,
      "agama_ayah": agamaAyah,
    };
    final response = await http.post(BaseUrl.ayah, body: {
      'id_register': ayah['id_register'],
      'nama_ayah': ayah['nama_ayah'],
      'agama_ayah': ayah['agama_ayah'],
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);
  }
```

Code to show dropdownbutton value

```
DropdownButton<String> _buildDropdownButtonAgama() {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: _dropdownValueAgm,
      onChanged: (String agamaAyah) {
        setState(() {
          _dropdownValueAgm = agamaAyah;
        });
      },
      items: <String>[
        'Katolik',
        'Kristen',
        'Islam',
        'Hindu',
        'Buddha',
        'Kong Hu Chu',
        'Kepercayaan'
      ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
 }
```

Return code to display ui

```
List<DemoItem<dynamic>> _demoItems;
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPref();
         return Form(
            key: _key,
            child: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return CollapsibleBody(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  onSave: () {
                    Form.of(context).save();
                    close();
                    _sumbit(namaAyah, agamaAyah);
                  },
                  onCancel: () {
                    Form.of(context).reset();
                    close();
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "ex. John john",
                            labelText: "Nama",
                          ),
                          onSaved: (e) => namaAyah = e,
                        ),
```

Dropdown button code

```
Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          ),
                          width: 320.0,
                          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                            child: ButtonTheme(
                              alignedDropdown: true,
                              child: _buildDropdownButtonAgama(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                  );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: so, what is the result from `_dropdownValueAgm `?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can on submit mathod please try below code:-

```
sumbit(String namaAyah,agamaAyah) async {
    var ayah = {
      "id_register": idReg,
      "nama_ayah": namaAyah,
      "agama_ayah": _dropdownValueAgm, //here i have change.
    };
    final response = await http.post(BaseUrl.ayah, body: {
      'id_register': ayah['id_register'],
      'nama_ayah': ayah['nama_ayah'],
      'agama_ayah': ayah['agama_ayah'],
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);
  }
```